# Can I optimize checking for multiple null values in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
if (Session["CurrentUrl"] != null & Session["CurrentHost"] != null)
```

I use this in many places. I am wondering if anyone can think of a way to optimize the C# code just to make things slight more clear.

Comment: Don't use a single & when comparing booleans. This could cause problems in (rare) cases.

Comment: The first step would be to provide an accurate example, I seriously doubt you want to perform a boolean & on those two Session variables.   The next step is not to try to optimize trivial things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems like a prime candidate for an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static bool HasHostAndUrl(this HttpSessionState session)
    {
        return session["CurrentUrl"] != null && session["CurrentHost"] != null;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
if (Session.HasHostAndUrl()) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Same idea as mine, but I like your method name better. Deleting mine and throwing my weight behind this one.

Comment: Thanks very much Jon and all the others. Marking Jon as accepted and up voting the rest.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (HostAndUrlExist()) {
    ...
}

public boolean HostAndUrlExist() {
    return Session["CurrentUrl"] != null && Session["CurrentHost"] != null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a method to return true or false

Answer (score 1):

If you have groups of session variables that you often use together, consider storing them as an object instead of as a set of primitive types.

Comment: I've no idea why this was downvoted. +1 to compensate, this is a very good observation.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method that takes one or more strings, like this:

```
public boolean SessionObjectsPresent(params string[] names) {
    foreach (var name in names) {
        if (Session[name] == null) return false
    }
    return true;
}


if (SessionObjectsPresent("CurrentHost", "CurrentUrl")) {
    // ...
}
```

The benefit of this approach becomes evident when you need to test session for other things:

```
if (SessionObjectsPresent("CurrentUser", "LastEditTime")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No because you then keep repeating the "CurrentHost" and "CurrentUrl" strings over and over in calls to `SessionObjectsPresent`.

Comment: @Jason what's the problem with being explicit about what you test?

Comment: @Jason Defining constants helps tremendously in this regard.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Yet...You didn't suggest that.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, the post is not tagged "homework", so I expect "small things", such as defining constants for numbers and strings that you use in more than one spot, to be obvious to anyone who gets paid for writing software :)

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to improve, like abstract a method with a meaningful name, or extract a interface `ISession` to make it more unit testable.